# Iam reading learning python the hard way, i am doing the first argv exercize and getting an error

Tags: python, python-2.7

In learning python the hard way exercise 13 we import `argv` for the first time. Here is the code:

```
from sys import argv

script, first, second, third = argv

print 'The script is called:' script
print 'Your first variable is:' first
print 'Your second variable is:' second
print 'Your third variable is:' third
```

And here is the output i am getting:

```
donny@donny:~/Documents/pygame-scripts$ python ex13.py first second third
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex13.py", line 1, in <module>
    d
NameError: name 'd' is not defined
```

I can't figure this out. I googled it and checked that i copied the code exactly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, i posted the wrong error. That error is from me trying to run it in python 3 just to see what would happen. The python 2 error is exactly the same though.

Comment: Now I realize i should have just edited the question instead of posting a comment. Sorry again. The question is edited.

Comment: Apart from the problem I mentioned (and solved) via [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31398427/897968), I am wondering if there is a problem with your source file - line 1 doesn't even contain any `d` characters..?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're missing commas between the arguments to `print`.

Try this instead:

```
from sys import argv

script, first, second, third = argv

print 'The script is called:', script
print 'Your first variable is:', first
print 'Your second variable is:', second
print 'Your third variable is:', third
```

**EDIT:**

To make your code compatible with Python 3, use `print(arg1, arg2)` instead of `print arg1, arg2`.

Answer (score 1):

Needs `,` after strings. Like as follows

```
print 'The script is called:', script
print 'Your first variable is:', first
print 'Your second variable is:', second
print 'Your third variable is:', third
```